# How to get code of a runtime version on Bluej

Tags: api, bluej

Ive been given a project on programing and our lecturer gave us a runtime version of what it should look like is there anyway of getting the code from this?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to cheat?
Surely, there is a reason your lecturer didn't give you the source.

I'd suggest you ask again if you have a question about learning to program, and not about being able to cheat without learning.

Comment: While what you are saying may be true, that is neither an answer nor helpful in any way.

Comment: not in anyway helpful i asked a question not for your opinion.